# Error with Column attribute with Name Nb_delays_90+_ever ( has special characters )

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have Code First table class with field :

```
   public class NBKI_Response
  {
    [Column("Nb_delays_90+_ever")]
    public int? Nb_delays_90__ever { get; set; }

    [Column("Nb_delays_90+_2y")]
    public int? Nb_delays_90__2y { get; set; }
   }
```

and I have Error "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name" while attempt add new record.

Why and how to fix ?

In database column has name exactly "Nb_delays_90+_ever" ...

**UPD:**  I'm not allowed change column name in database

**UPD2:** Script for table ( I use Code First from existing database):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[NBKI_Response](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[External_Data_Id] [int] NULL,
[Total_accounts] [int] NULL,
[Total_negative_accounts] [int] NULL,
[Total_active_accounts] [int] NULL,
[Total_credit_limit] [int] NULL,
[Total_overdue_amount] [int] NULL,
[Total_outstanding_amount] [int] NULL,
[Total_installment_amount] [int] NULL,
[Total_disputed] [int] NULL,
[Total_letigation] [int] NULL,
[Total_bankruptcy] [int] NULL,
[Total_inquiries] [int] NULL,
[Recent_inquiries] [int] NULL,
[Recent_account_date] [datetime] NULL,
[Oldest_account_date] [datetime] NULL,
[Nb_delays_5_30_ever] [int] NULL,
[Nb_delays_30_60_ever] [int] NULL,
[Nb_delays_60_90_ever] [int] NULL,
[Nb_delays_90+_ever] [int] NULL,
[Nb_delays_5_30_2y] [int] NULL,
[Nb_delays_30_60_2y] [int] NULL,
[Nb_delays_60_90_2y] [int] NULL,
[Nb_delays_90+_2y] [int] NULL,
[Own_active_accounts_nb] [int] NULL,
[Max_overdue] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
[RCC_credit_limit] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
[rcc_outstanding_amount] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
[Nb_active_mortgages] [int] NULL,
[Nb_active_microcredits] [int] NULL,
[Total_mortgages] [int] NULL,
[Total_microcredits] [int] NULL,
[Nb_active_consumer_credit] [int] NULL,
[Nb_active_rcc] [int] NULL,
[Total_consumer_credit] [int] NULL,
[Total_rcc] [int] NULL,
[Is_FICO] [bit] NULL,
[Fico_score_v2] [int] NULL,
[Fico_score_v3] [int] NULL,
[Is_SocialLink] [bit] NULL,
[SocialLink] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_NBKI_Response] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

**UPD3** After add tracing by:

```
db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
```

I see that mapping by column attribute don't working:

```
INSERT [dbo].[NBKI_Response]([External_Data_Id], [Total_accounts], 
[Total_negative_accounts], [Total_active_accounts], [Total_credit_limit],             
[Total_overdue_amount], [Total_outstanding_amount], 
[Total_installment_amount], [Total_disputed], [Total_letigation], 
[Total_bankruptcy], [Total_inquiries], [Recent_inquiries], 
[Recent_account_date], [Oldest_account_date], [Nb_delays_5_30_ever], 
[Nb_delays_30_60_ever], [Nb_delays_60_90_ever], [Nb_delays_90__ever], 
[Nb_delays_5_30_2y], [Nb_delays_30_60_2y], [Nb_delays_60_90_2y], 
[Nb_delays_90__2y], [Own_active_accounts_nb], [Max_overdue], 
[RCC_credit_limit], [rcc_outstanding_amount], [Nb_active_mortgages], 
[Nb_active_microcredits], [Total_mortgages], [Total_microcredits], 
[Nb_active_consumer_credit], [Nb_active_rcc], [Total_consumer_credit], 
[Total_rcc], [Is_FICO], [Fico_score_v2], [Fico_score_v3], [Is_SocialLink], 
[SocialLink])
VALUES (NULL, @0, @1, @2, @3, @4, NULL, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, NULL, @10, @11, 
@12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, NULL, NULL, NULL, @21, @22, 
NULL, NULL, @23, @24, @25, @26, @27, NULL, @28, NULL, NULL)
SELECT [ID]
FROM [dbo].[NBKI_Response]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [ID] = scope_identity()
```

Comment: Any chance you could use a column name that doesn't contain special characters? They are a serious pain to deal with.

Comment: Sorry - but I can't change database...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't repro for me either on EF 6.1 or EF Core 2.

eg

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace Ef6Test
{


    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Column("Nb_delays_90+_ever")]
        public int? Nb_delays_90__ever { get; set; }
    }

    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);           
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Db>());

            using (var db = new Db())
            {

                db.Database.Log = m => Console.WriteLine(m);
                db.Database.Initialize(true);

                var f = new Foo();
                f.Nb_delays_90__ever = 2;

                db.Foos.Add(f);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 2017-11-01 20:00:22,974 ERROR NBKI_Response Add error - System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'Nb_delays_90__ever'.
Invalid column name 'Nb_delays_90__2y'.

Comment: "Nb_delays_90__ever" there's something wrong with the mapping.  Do you have anything in OnModelCreating?

Comment: only `public virtual DbSet<NBKI_Response> NBKI_Response { get; set; }` Inside OnModelCreating NBKI_Response don't use

Comment: You'll either need to start with my sample, and add stuff until it fails, or start with your project and remove stuff until it works.

Comment: Thank you very much - in all cases your example working well - so reason error is different !

Comment: When I found reason - I add my solution and why this error happened !

Comment: how it's possible - the same client, the same EF 6.1.3, the same column names on the same MS-SQL Server ( only database was different) - in one case column mapped well, in other - don't working ???!!!